# XAMPP for macbook change root location

Tags: php, xampp

I use xampp

I want change root folder for my project

In httpd.conf I change the root address, but not work for me:

```
DocumentRoot "~/Users/mohammad/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Project/Website"
<Directory "~/Users/mohammad/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Project/Website">
```

And I get this error::

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
mohammads-macbook-pro.local
Apache/2.4.47 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.19 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1
```

Comment: So did you do the things it suggests in the error to try and fix it? Check the folder permissions (remember the apache account is not the same as your personal user account), and make sure there's an index file.

Comment: @ADyson I check permision. is 777

Comment: Please change `~/Users/` to `/Users/` and retry. (Let's know the result)

Comment: @ParsaNikoo did you add an index.html file also?

Comment: @KenLee i tested it. but not work

Comment: @ADyson yes i have

Comment: Apart from the directory, please make sure that index.html is also read allowed .

Comment: Permission may need to be set on parent folders also to make it accessible to apache